# Concatenate dictionary with empty values

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, concatenation

Magic commands and... dictionaries created and in a list. "d1" is the most complete dictionary, because have data for all rows. 
But d2, d3 and d4 don have data for all rows.

```
file1 used to created d1:
    key1    x1  x2  x3
    key2    y1  y2  y3
    key3    z1  z2  z3
    key4    w1  w2  w3
    key5    k1  k2  k3
    key6    q1  q2  q3

file2 used to created d2:
    key1    x4  x5  x6
    key2    y4  y5  y6
    key3    z4  z5  z6
    key6    q4  q5  q6

file3 used to created d3:
    key2    y7
    key3    z7
    key6    q7

file4 used to created d4:
    key3    z8
    key4    w8
    key5    k8
```

Sorry to put the example files but I think that it could useful for other.

Here is the problem:

```
dicts = [d1, d2, d3, d4] # my dictionary list
new_dict = {}

for d in [d1, d2, d3, d4]:
    for key in d:
        if key not in new_dict:
            new_dict[key] = d[key]
        else:
            new_dict[key] += d[key]

for k, v in new_dict.iteritems():
    print (k+'\t'+ ('\t'.join(v)))
```

My expected table should be like this, with empty spaces when I don't have the value.

```
    key1    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
    key2    y1  y2  y3  y4  y5  y6  y7
    key3    z1  z2  z3  z4  z5  z6  z7  z8
    key4    w1  w2  w3                  w8      
    key5    k1  k2  k3                  k8
    key6    q1  q2  q3              q7
```

But the most far I could reach was this:

```
    key1    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
    key2    y1  y2  y3  y4  y5  y6  y7
    key3    z1  z2  z3  z4  z5  z6  z7  z8
    key4    w1  w2  w3  w8      
    key5    k1  k2  k3  k8
    key6    q1  q2  q3  q7
```

How can I include the empty/null values in the case they don' t exist?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use `format` printing. Also, you should consider using a `defaultdict` or at least the `setdefault` method of plain `dict`. Finally, it seems to me you want your data to be ordered, so I'm not sure if dicts are the way to go.

Comment: Could you give me some example how to use this functions in this script?

Comment: This would be infinitely easier if you used `pandas`. Sorry, right now I'm on my phone and I can't really write any code. But look up examples of these things. You also may want to look at `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Do you always know ahead of time how many "columns" you will have?

Comment: @FelipeLira You need to explain how the algorithm would know to vertically align values such as `z8`, `w8`, etc (I assume that those are not the literal values). For example, when processing `d3` how will the code know to align the `q7` with `z7` rather than with `z4` or some other value? In other words, how will the algorithm examine a value and determine which column it belongs in? That issue is not clear in your current specification of the problem.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the final dict, in this case, has 9 columns, including the keys, and 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each dict `d`, you'll want to populate the lists in `new_dict` to be the same size, with an empty/null value (e.g. `None`).

```
for d in ...:
    ...
    size = max(map(len, new_dict.values()))
    for value in new_dict.values():
        value += [None] * (size - len(value))
```

And seconding the suggestion to consider `defaultdict` or `setdefault`.